# how to count the array values?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I will count my array value.

This is my array :
$ar =array(10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20)

I need to count my value array, like the following:
10 there is 4
20 there is 3
30 there is 1
50 there is 1

how to do it?

Comment: I think [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) is precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: See the function `array_count_values()`.